# What paint absorbed the most infrared light?

Tags: infrared-radiation

Is Parents recently installed drainage gutters on the back part of there house.  The problem is they did not take into account the location of their security cameras. So now at night the infrared light admitted from the cameras are being reflected back from the down spouts of the gutters. Moving the gutters and cameras is out of the question because of the time, labor and cost involved. So I'm left with only the option of painting the gutters. Is there a special paint or color the will not reflect back as much infrared light or completely absorb the infrared light?

Comment: Note that most of the information in your post is *completely unnecessary* for us to answer your question. I suggest you edit your question, leaving out the entire backstory and sticking to the actual question.

Comment: there are matte black paints , super black paints and carbon nanotubes paints. It's not colors but materials for surface treatment with the right spectrum. For domestic purposes, a matte black paint does the work

Comment: Take whatever cans of paint you already have and paint a section of the gutter that is in view of the camera.  You'll be able to see if some are better at not reflecting so much IR.

Comment: @igael In addition there are "paints" whose absorbing capability is based on essentially surface roughness.  The uneven surface (at the tens to hundreds of micron level) creates traps which lead to absorption after N reflections inside each trap.

Comment: Maybe this is tangential to your question, but glass is opaque to infrared.  If you have access to a thermal camera, took at someone wearing glasses.  If you could surround your sensor with glass, you might be able to reduce your noise.

Comment: Mask the cameras' view so as to block the sight line to the downspouts.

Comment: Probably [Vanta black](https://www.surreynanosystems.com/vantablack/faqs) which is absorbing 99.85% of incident IR.